# Use image instead of a color in linear-gradient

Tags: html, css

I am using `background: linear-gradient(110deg, #ecf0fa 60%, #223f5c 60%);
}` and want to place an image instead of the second color to have the  background image "cutted". Is this somehow possible with the linear gradient?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="background">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #ecf0fa 60%, #223f5c 60%);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abosv38d/1/

Comment: use the usual image tag and put `linear-gradient` on `opacity` property, interpolating from 100% to 0%, didn't try this, but something like this should work

Comment: No you can't use an image as a color. It sounds like you're trying to fade in a gradient to a color **in** the image...is that right? If not, please provide an image of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D I would like to replace the dark blue (#223f5c) with an image, to cut the image like the gradient does.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what this is supposed to look like.